# Pythonic way to club labels of categorical feature

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a feature column in a data frame which has multiple labels

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zRpm.png)

I want to club labels into EA, CAR and Others categories. I have achieved this writing IFELSE statement. Is there any pythonic way to this elegantly.

```
def clubUOM(label):
    
    if label =='EA':
        return 'EA'
    elif label =='CAR':
        return 'CAR'
    else:
        return 'Others'
    
data1['UOM'] = data1['UOM'].map(clubUOM)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `isin`:

```
df.loc[~df['UOM'].isin(['EA','CAR']), 'UOM'] = 'Others'
```

You can also do `where` or `np.where`:

```
df['UOM'] = df['UOM'].where(df['UOM'].isin(['EA','CAR']), 'Others')
```